# General solution to Diophantine equation in 3 variables

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, euclidean-algorithm

I need to use Euclidean algorithm and find general solution to Diophantine equation given as

$6x+15y+20z=1$

This can be represented as

$6x+5a=1$ (1)

$15y+20z=5$ (2)

Solution to (1) is $(1+5i,-1-6i)$ and (2) is $(-1+20j,1-15j)$.

Note I can get general solution using Euler algorithm and it is

$x=a$

$y=-2b+1$

$z=3b-3a-1$

$a,b$ - integers

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: yes (1) and (2) need to be combined to give general solution. i think (2) is $((-1+20j)a, (1-15j)a)$ but i need to check.

Comment: What about your "general solution using Euler algorithm"?

Comment: i need to get the same using Euclidean algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

Express (2) as

$3y+4z=1$

The solution is $(-1+4j,1-3j)$.

The multiple of 5 is $(-5+4j,5-3j)$.

The multiple of 5 and a is $(5+30i+4j,-5-30i-3j)$.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to $3y+4z=1$ is $(-1+20j,1-15j)$; therefore the solution to $3y+4z=-1-6i$ is $([-1-6i][-1+20j],[-1-6i][1-15j])$.

Hence the general solution to $6x+15y+20z=1$ is $$\boxed{(x,y,z)\ =\ (1+5i,[-1-6i][-1+20j],[-1-6i][1-15j])}$$

Check:
$$\begin{array}{rl} & 6(1+5i)+15(-1-6i)(-1+20j)+20(-1-6i)(1-15j) \\ =&  6(1+5i)+15(1+6i-20j-120ij)+20(-1-6i+15j+90ij) \\ =& 6+30i+15+90i-300j-1800ij-20-120i+300j+1800ij \\ =& 1\end{array}$$